# unity: How to develop for HTC VIVE Pro without having the VIVE device

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vudroid

I have been requested to buil an application with AR, and targeting VIVE™ PRO Headset, I don't have the physical headset.
in android we used to use Virtual machine, Is there similar thing in VIVE™ ?
*I work with unity*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simulator to develop for HTC VIVE Pro without the device itself. To enable it, go to *Edit* ---> *Preferences* ---> *VIU Settings* and check the Simulator check-box. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/ViveSoftware/ViveInputUtility-Unity/wiki/Simulator).

[image]

Comment: Note that if you have a vice devices connected, it will use it instead of Simulator so it must be disconnected for simulator to work.

Comment: I will just note that you should buy the device (or borrow and test with one) before releasing your game. The simulator is never 100% representative of the input, display, or other feature.

Comment: Of course. It's just a temporary thing and you should even test the app on the device once in a while on the device before the project is complete or you might even run into issues when you decide to test the whole project on the device.

Comment: "As often as possible, as early as possible." Definitely. How much you need it depends on the project and the developer's experience, so an experienced developer can probably get away with borrowing a set once or twice just to validate their mental model. But they're also the people more likely to own a device.